# downloading a file from amazon s3 account to another s3 account using php

Tags: php, amazon-s3, cakephp-1.2

Hi I'm really new to amazon s3. I want to download a file to my server (which is in s3) from a given another s3 location (credentials will be provided). This must be done using a php (cakephp 1.2) method and there is no user interface for this. (this could be a cron job probably). I couldn't find any good article regarding this by googling. Any sample code that I can do this work?

Comment: Presumably your server is an EC2 instance, because there is no such thing as a server 'in S3' - right?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/).

Comment: check it before. Couldn't find any valuable information for this

Comment: Did you check the Code Samples? They have an example of downloading a file from S3 in there: `$response = $s3->get_object('aws-sdk-for-php', 'demo/big-buck-bunny.mp4', array(
  'fileDownload' => './downloads/big-buck-bunny.mp4'
 ));`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to copy an [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) object (file) from one AWS account to a different AWS account without downloading and uploading it to a separate system (apparently an [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance)?!

It is possible to copy an object within a single account by means of [copyObject()](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#copyObject), but cross account operations aren't supported by this API (and neither for any other AWS resources, as far as I know, which is likely a deliberate decision to ease and streamline the security architecture and process).

So while your use case is sound, there is no other solution than channeling this process through your server, i.e. download from the source account and upload to the target account.

This shouldn't be much of a problem cost or performance wise though, because *There is no Data Transfer charge between Amazon EC2 and other Amazon Web Services within the same region (i.e. between Amazon EC2 US West and Amazon S3 in US West)* (see section *Data Transfer* in [Amazon EC2 Pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing)) and these operations will facilitate Amazon's decent internal network infrastructure (rather than crossing the public internet).

Comment: It is ok if I can download the particular file in the particular account to my account. What do u mean by " download from the source account and upload to the target account". The target account is my account and my server is running their. May be I didn't get the exact architect of the S3. Can't I just download that file to my account?

Comment: There might be some confusion regarding the different AWS services: [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) _is storage for the Internet_ - it is really just that, storage, so you can't run a server on it etc.; on the other hand, [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) _provides resizable compute capacity in the cloud_ - slightly simplified this boils down to running servers on demand, and your server is probably such an EC2 instance accordingly. Both EC2 and S3 (and in fact all AWS services) are usually accessed via a single AWS account.

Comment: So the question is whether you want to download from an S3 bucket stored in your AWS account to an EC2 instance running in your AWS account, or want to copy an object (file) from one S3 bucket in your AWS account to another S3 bucket in your AWS account.

Comment: Yes the requirement is this. Users have videos on their S3. I want to download a copy of that video from their S3 to my EC2 directory.